# Problems with laptop cooling fan

Tags: linux-mint, laptop

This is what's happening:

I decide to set up my laptop sensors for watching my processor temperature, and I then use `pwmconfig` to get my fan cooling my processor right. It all works out, but here's the catch: When I close my laptop lid and in turn suspend it, the temperature of my cpu is locked at 26 degrees celsius, and my fan's RPM is stuck at 0, and will randomly flicker to the speed it should go for 26 C. I have no choice but to stop the `fancontrol` daemon and let my fan be full speed all the time. This doesn't affect my battery much, but I'm more worried about the lifetime of the fan. Any help would be much appreciated.

Info:

I'm running Linux Mint Sarah with the `4.4.0-28-generic` kernel.

the sensor I'm using is called `dell_ssm-virtual-0` using the CPU temperature, and none of the ambient.

I am using a Dell Inspiron 11 3147.

lspci results:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 2280 (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 21)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc (rev 21)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 22a3 (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 2284 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22c8 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 2292 (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)
```

lsmod results:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69632  2
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
ctr                    16384  2
ccm                    20480  2
bnep                   20480  2
hid_rmi                24576  0
dell_wmi               16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
dell_led               16384  1
dell_laptop            20480  0
intel_rapl             20480  0
binfmt_misc            20480  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
kvm_intel             172032  0
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
kvm                   536576  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
dell_smm_hwmon         16384  0
arc4                   16384  2
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
hid_sensor_incl_3d     16384  0
hid_sensor_rotation    16384  0
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
uvcvideo               90112  0
hid_sensor_als         16384  0
hid_sensor_gyro_3d     16384  0
hid_sensor_accel_3d    16384  0
hid_sensor_magn_3d     16384  0
punit_atom_debug       16384  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
iwlmvm                311296  0
btusb                  45056  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
hid_sensor_trigger     16384  12 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_magn_3d
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  6 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_magn_3d
kfifo_buf              16384  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
industrialio           57344  9 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,industrialio_triggered_buffer,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_als,kfifo_buf,hid_sensor_magn_3d
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
mac80211              737280  1 iwlmvm
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
hid_sensor_iio_common    16384  7 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_magn_3d
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
btintel                16384  1 btusb
aesni_intel           167936  4
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
hid_multitouch         20480  0
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
shpchp                 36864  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
lpc_ich                24576  0
mei_txe                20480  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_txe
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
int3400_thermal        16384  0
int3403_thermal        16384  0
tpm_crb                16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
dell_rbtn              16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 processor_thermal_device,int3403_thermal
mac_hid                16384  0
soc_button_array       16384  0
acpi_pad               20480  0
coretemp               16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
btrfs                 987136  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              102400  1 btrfs
hid_sensor_custom      20480  0
hid_sensor_hub         20480  9 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_custom,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_iio_common
dm_mirror              24576  0
dm_region_hash         24576  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
usbhid                 49152  0
i915                 1208320  4
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        147456  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               126976  0
drm                   360448  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    20480  2 dell_led,dell_wmi
video                  40960  3 i915,dell_wmi,dell_laptop
i2c_hid                20480  0
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
hid                   118784  5 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch,hid_sensor_hub,hid_rmi,usbhid
fjes                   28672  0
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
pinctrl_cherryview     32768  1
```

Comment: If it can reassure you, fans usually operate better and longer when running at full speed.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I'm mainly worried about accumulating dust.

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old question but I had a similar issue and turned to be a bug in the system (Linux Mint) related to nvidia drivers. After updating the problem was gone.

Comment: After updating ... the whole system? The kernel? the drivers?

Comment: After updating nvidia drivers + some mint core packages, but I suspect that the bug was in the nvidia package